# Adding a subview to view changes other subviews' frames

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiview, addsubview

A `uiviewcontroller` has two `UIViews` and one `tableview` added in stroyboard ib and connected with `IBoutlet`

when user click swipe in top uiview, I call following method to change frames of all subview IBoutlet elements. That works.

```
-(void)hideTopViews
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [_overallHealth setHidden:YES];
        _overallHealth.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width,0);
        [_healthBar setHidden:YES];
        _sortView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 45,self.view.frame.size.width,_sortView.frame.size.height);
        _portfoList.frame =  CGRectMake(0, _sortView.frame.origin.x+_sortView.bounds.size.height+50,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
        _sortButton.frame =  CGRectMake(90, 45,_sortButton.frame.size.width,_sortButton.frame.size.height);
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_sortButton];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems=nil;
    }];


}
```

However when I add another subview programmatically to self.view all subviews goes back to their original positions like in storyboard.

```
-(void)showPortfolioDetailsScreen
{
    PortfolioDetails *portView=[[PortfolioDetails alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,200,200,200)];
    portView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:portView];

}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tanzolone is on right track, if you are using only portrait mode and want your storyboard to stop changes your subviews to original frames go to your storyboard and uncheck `Use Autolayout`

so you can use the old struts-and-springs model.

here is a detailed tutorial of autolayouts though 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: How can I solve this issue without removing autolayout?is it possible?